# Merge two arrays in a zipper pattern

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

Say I have two arrays
[1, 3 , 5] and
[2, 4, 6],
what's the best way of merging them to yield [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] without using loops or recursion and just numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`:

```
np.array((a,b)).T.ravel()
```

or when `a,b` might not be of the same size:

```
np.array(list(zip(a,b))).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = [2, 4, 6]
sorted([*a, *b])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `numpy`:

Just add them, `a = [1,3,5]+[2,4,6]` and then sort them `sorted(a)`

Comment: I think what the OP wants is a way to produce a list or array of interleaved values from each of the input lists, not a way to sort them.

Comment: I also understood it this way

Answer (score 0):

In pure python you can use

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*zip(array1, array2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
[x for t in zip(a,b) for x in t]
```

Note that this is equivalent to explicit loops in the same order

```
out = []
for t in zip(a,b):
   for x in t:
       out.append(x)
```